# limit as x tends to 1

Tags: integration, limits

Let $G(X)=$$\int_{z=x}^{x^2}   f(z) \,dz$

Find the limit of G(x)as x tends to 1.

I have found $G'x=2xf(x^2)-f(x)$ but not sure on how to solve this question, any  help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: For what stands $z$ here?

Comment: another function in terms of z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G(x)=\int_1^{x^2}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_1^{x^2}f(z)\,\mathrm dz-\int_1^xf(z)\,\mathrm dz$, $G$ is continuous (any function of the type $x\mapsto\int_a^x\varphi(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is continuous, as long as $\varphi$ is Riemann-integrable) and therefore the limit that you're after is $G(1)$, which is equal to $0$.